# Openfire's ofMessageArchive information

Tags: mysql, xmpp, openfire

How many days of message history records are stored in the **ofMessageArchive** table for openfire 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

Log In to your openfire panel and goto

> server -> Archiving -> Archiving Settings

and you'll find

> "Max Message Age:"

It is The maximum number of days to keep messages before purging them from the database.

by default it is 30 days you can change that value..

Comment: also you need to check  Archive one-to-one chats  
and Archive group chats for archiving msgs.